# Timezone issue with Date field in salesforce

Tags: apex

In salesforce organization Time Zone    is (GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (Europe/London). and customer portal user Time Zone is (GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles)

Implemented code in Rest service API

Using POSTMAN

customer portal user Access token, method as POST ,given date as 06/01/2014 and created a record in salesforce Date as 06/01/2014.

customer portal user Access token, method as GET, Displaying Date as 04/01/2014 and salesforce  record Date as 06/01/2014.

why i am getting date as 04/01/2014. In salesforce it had value as 06/01/2014
Any reason behind why i am getting 04/01/2014.

Comment: Can you please share your REST API code for analysis?

Comment: It has 1000 lines of code for my REST API. when i change customer portal user Time Zone  to (GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (Europe/London) that time i am getting date as 06/01/2014. i think it only varies on timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is Time Zone issue only. In your post request, you need to convert date to GMT+00:00 format and then save it to salesforce.

```
DateTime departureDateTimeGMTFormat = Datetime.newInstanceGmt( DeptDate.year(), DeptDate.month(), DeptDate.day(), integer.Valueof(DeptTime.substring(0, 2)),integer.Valueof( DeptTime.substring(2, 4)),00 );

DeptDateTime = departureDateTimeGMTFormat.format( 'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm' , 'GMT+5:30');
```

Comment: Do this solves your problem? If yes then please mark up vote.

Comment: Do u have any example on convert date to GMT format ?

Comment: I have added example in my answer above, Please check it